# Fullpage.js continuousVertical = true pauses videos

Tags: jquery, html5-video, fullpage.js

Fullpagejs `continuousVertical: true` property pauses my videos when looping from the last to first slide and vice versa.

This is my js code:

```
continuousVertical: true,
afterRender: function() {
    $('video').each(function() { 
        $(this).get(0).play(); 
    });
}
```

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you want a plugin like that to pause your videos when changing from one section to another so the visitor won't miss anything from it. I wouldn't worry too much about it.

In any case, if you really want to play it again, just force the play on the `afterLoad` of the first or last section. (or both)

```
afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index){
    if(index == 1 || index == $('.fp-section').length){
        $('video').each(function() { 
           $(this).get(0).play(); 
        });
    }
}
```